# PHP MYSQL get array numbers while fetching

Tags: php, row, fetch

Following a query, a mysql_fetch_array generates an array of results that have a sequential number in them that you can get, I believe, by putting [] at the end of the field.

While fetching I want to set sequential ids for divs as in `<div id="row1">` to keep track of the rows being returned.  Row is just a word, not a variable.   Is there an easy way to append a number to row based on the array number--something like row[] without having to set up a counter?   Thanks.

Comment: The best solution for this, is most likely to just implement a counter

Comment: but why? you typed more in your question than to implement a counter..

Comment: I want to give the rows id#s so javascript knows which are which (using get_element_by_id)

Comment: what is the problem implementing the counter, you only need one extra line of code?

Comment: Counter version would be as follows but Would prefer not to set up yet another counter if it is possible to get arraynum.

$i=0
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
echo '<div id="row'.$i.'"> Row 1 text</div>'
$i = $i+1;
}

Comment: Since already fetching an array, I thought there might be a more elegant solution than counters.  I have enough of them as it is and they get confusing.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to set up a counter which i don't understand why, and if you have something like id as table row (your primary key) that is being fetched from the database then you can do it like this.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) { 
    echo '<div id="row'.row['id'].'"> Row '.$row['id'].' text</div>';
}
```